# Is there a Freemarker String Built-in or Output Format for OWASP JavaScript encoding to avoid XSS?

Tags: javascript, xss, freemarker, owasp

I couldn't find any already ready to use String Built-in or Output Format for [OWASP JavaScript encoding to avoid XSS](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#output-encoding-rules-summary), could you?:

> Except for alphanumeric characters, encode all characters with the \uXXXX unicode encoding format (X = Integer).

Actually I'm looking for something like [here](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/preventing)'s `How to prevent XSS client-side in JavaScript` section:

```js
function jsEscape(str){
  return String(str).replace(/[^\w. ]/gi, function(c){
     return '\\u'+('0000'+c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
  });

}
```

If not, does it make sense to pull request such capability? because I'm wondering why such common important functionality is already missing in Freemarker!

### Example

Assume following simple hypothetical FTL file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ${parameters.id}Array = new Array(${parameters.size});
</script>
```

I would like to ask Freemarker to encode/escape `id` and `size` if they contain scripts (as per above provided links from OWASP etc). For instance an XSS attack could be `id` = `dummy=0; alert('XSS'); actualId`. Freemarker currently produces:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dummy=0; alert('XSS'); actualIdArray = new Array(1);
</script>
```

But I'm looking for:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dummy\u003d0\u003b alert\u0028\u0027XSS\u0027\u0029\u003b actualIdArray = new Array(1);
</script>
```

which won't run XSS as expected (avoids XSS but allows not XSS `id` and `size`).

As you see it's a common required functionality as per [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#output-encoding-rules-summary):

> Except for alphanumeric characters, encode all characters with the \uXXXX unicode encoding format (X = Integer).

Comment: Tried https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_js_string ?

Comment: @JasperdeVries yes, it was my first try. It doesn't escape javascript's scripts but javascript's String literals: "Escapes the string with the escaping rules of JavaScript language string literals, so it's safe to insert the value into a string literal." it's said. e.g. doesn't escape }{;)( chars.

Comment: @YasserZamani Inside a JavaScript string literal, the `}{;)(` characters has no special meaning, as far as I know. Can you show a concrete example of the problem?

Comment: @ddekany thanks for comment! I added an example to the question.

Comment: I see. That's a strange safely function, as it makes the JavaScript syntactically invalid. Surely that's far less dangerous than without it, but shouldn't the escaping function just be something like `${parameters.id?jsIdentifier}`, that will throw exception if there's any funny character in `parameters.id`?

Comment: Thanks @ddekany for the follow up! I don't think so because it's not always an identifier, for instance `var myVar = new Array(${parameters.size})`. The `size` isn't an identifier but must be encoded to avoid XSS. BTW please consider also it's not always syntactically wrong e.g. `var \u0024My\u0024Var = "$My$Var";` is correct.

Comment: The thing with these escaping/checking functions is always that how to do them properly depends not only on the language but on the context in the output. But it seems while this `\u` escaping is not truly correct, it happens to be an "one size fits all" solution against many kind of JS XSS. So yeah, I think it will be added. Note however that if a malicious user can specify any variable name, even if it's a valid name, that can be used for bad purposes.

Comment: @ddekany yes I do agree and I've already changed my design using Map and Freemarker's `?js_string` e.g. `var MyMap = new Map(); MyMap.set("${parameters.id?js_string}, new Array(${parameters.size}));`. The `size` still needs this encoding functionality I think albeit.

Comment: If we are purists, `size` must be a number (otherwise, even if you apply `\u` escaping, someone could inject the name of a variable there, which you didn't intend to allow). If it's ensured to be number in the data-model, it needs no escaping. Otherwise you could write `size?number?c`.

Comment: you're right @ddekany, at least in this case we can protect js using Map and `?number?c`. So I'm not sure anymore if this feature is required in Freemarker or not! Currently can't imagine a case